# Multiply two DF using numpy, calculate average per line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, average

df: aux contains boolean values and rtrnM contains monthly returns. I am looking to (piecewise) multiply aux and rtrnM to get a df with the monthly returns where aux is TRUE and subsequently I want to calculate the arithmetic mean of the resulting values per line.
This is how aux and rtrnM look like:

```
In [341]: aux.tail()
Out[341]: 
              IWB    SPY    VGK    IEV    EWJ    EPP    IEF    SHY    IAU
2017-06-30  False  False   True   True   True  False  False  False  False
2017-07-31   True  False  False  False   True   True  False  False  False
2017-08-31  False  False   True   True  False   True  False  False  False
2017-09-29  False  False  False  False  False   True   True  False   True
2017-10-31   True  False   True   True  False  False  False  False  False

In [342]: rtrnM.tail()
Out[342]: 
                 IWB       SPY       VGK       IEV       EWJ       EPP  \
2017-06-30  0.007147  0.006374 -0.005148 -0.005326  0.013241  0.022903   
2017-07-31  0.019115  0.020554  0.028291  0.026850  0.020690  0.044065   
2017-08-31  0.003207  0.002918  0.000707 -0.000879 -0.000913  0.004091   
2017-09-29  0.020612  0.020141  0.032114  0.030790  0.018278 -0.008364   
2017-10-31  0.023163  0.023405  0.001372  0.003200  0.032490  0.024870   

                 IEF       SHY       IAU  
2017-06-30 -0.005097 -0.000786 -0.021311  
2017-07-31  0.003756  0.001860  0.023451  
2017-08-31  0.014574  0.002022  0.040917  
2017-09-29 -0.014407 -0.001867 -0.032233  
2017-10-31 -0.003018 -0.001037 -0.000812
```

tried this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame((aux * rtrnM).mean(axis=1),columns=['mthly'])
```

which doesn't give me the correct result. Any help would be appreciated. Guessing numpy is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the `mean` here gives you the mean across all values, including the 0-vals too.

The fix is easy. Call `sum` and divide by the number of non-zero values.

```
(aux * rtrnM).sum(1) / aux.sum(1)

2017-06-30    0.000922
2017-07-31    0.027957
2017-08-31    0.001306
2017-09-29   -0.018335
2017-10-31    0.009245
dtype: float64
```

Fashion a new dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(aux.mul(rtrnM).sum(1).div(aux.sum(1)), columns=['mthly'])
df

               mthly
2017-06-30  0.000922
2017-07-31  0.027957
2017-08-31  0.001306
2017-09-29 -0.018335
2017-10-31  0.009245
```

Comment: great. thanks so much. To be clear sum(1) means the sum per line?

Comment: @steff Correct, it is the sum along the first axis.